# VisualStudio XAML Live Debugging Tools in UWP

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create some in app menu tool like the one "Visual Studio XAML Live Debugging" has
[image: In App menu]

This menu is working bot for WPF and UWP, I did some researches how is done.
My findings are that VS uses **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.dll"** and **"Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.UwpTap.dll"** dll's form "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics" for this functionality. The WPF case is pretty simple VS loads this dll to debugged process and creates separate window (HWND) for hosting this menu. But for UWP the things are a little bit complicated the VS also loads the UwpTap.dll to debugged process but in this case this menu is not separate window (HWND) I checked with Spy++. The UwpTap.dll contains InAppMenu XAML as resource (Checked with DotPeek ) and this XAML is used display menu content. My questions is how this Menu (XAML) is attached to UWP app? How can I show such menu in any UWP app? If it is uses the application window XAML tree for loading this controls it should be found by walking through VisulaTree but can't. Could someone help me.

Comment: Interesting idea. But I don't think UWP could do what WPF does. You need to create a similar menu by yourself in the xaml instead of using Visual Studio's dll.

Comment: I didn't use VS dll's I have created my own one and I'm able to load it to any running UWP app but the thing is that this menu should not modify their XAML tree as it can break them. If you run Visual Studio and attach to any running UWP app it will also add  in app menu but the XAML as I understand is not changed. I think the UWP has some other API that allow to do that but my revers engineering skill is not enough to find that.